# How to get two tables aligned next to each other both at the top of the page

Tags: html, css

I am looking to get these two boxes to align next to each other side by side but all I keep generating is two boxes with one that is centered on the page and very small and cause the other box to shrink when text is typed into it. The tables are located in a php section of the page.

```
echo "<table style='width:100%;'><tr><td>";
echo "<div style='min-height:500px;margin-top: 10px;'><table style='-moz-border-radius:  15px;border-radius: 15px;border-bottom:1px solid gray;align: left;float: left;background- color:white;margin: auto;width: 75%;'><tr style='font-weight:bold;'><td></td><td>Title</td> <td>Date</td><td>City</td></tr>";
//header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
$abcd = $row['fname'];
 echo "<tr><td><img src='../login/image/".$row['name']."'  style='width: 125px;height: 94px;'></td>";
 echo '<td><form action="deals.php" method="get" style="margin:0px;"><input type="hidden" value="';
 echo $abcd;
 echo '" name="name"><input type="submit" style="background-color: white;border: none;color: #FF0000;text-decoration: underline;" name="submit2" value="';
 echo $abcd;
echo '"></form><br/>';
echo "</td><td>".$row['stdate']."</td>";
echo "</td><td>".$row['city']."</td></tr>";
$y++;
}
echo "</table></div>";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "<div style='-moz-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;height:10%;width: 50%;padding: 30px;background-color:white;align: right;float: right;margin: auto;margin-top:5px;'>"; 
 echo "</td></table>";
```

Comment: why are you echoing all html content?

Comment: The tables are in a php section

Answer (score 1):

It is better to separate your CSS and PHP Script so that it will be clearer to see your CSS properties.
Try to append a variable instead of adding echo each time.
You wrote "**align**" instead of "**text-align**" for your style probably.

```
$string = "<table style='width:100%;'><tr><td>";
$string .= "<div class="my-style"><table>";
$string .= "...";
```

Then in your CSS file :

```
.my-style {
min-height:500px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.my-style table {
-moz-border-radius:15px;
border-radius: 15px;
border-bottom:1px solid gray;
text-align: left;
float: left;
background- color:white;
margin: auto;width: 75%;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want two tables side by side :

```
.table1 {
    width:auto;
    max-width:49%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.table2 {
    width:auto;
    max-width:49%;
    display:block;
    float:right;
}
```